# Setting layout of a CustomView based on user input

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have a custom view extending the RelativeLayout. In the init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) method of this class I set the layout file by:

```
inflate(getContext(), R.layout.in_session_view_layout, this);
```

I am using this custom view in a list item like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:verizon="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_margin="5dp">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

</FrameLayout>

    <com.widgets.FreeBeeNotificationView
        android:id="@+id/freebee_pre_session_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        verizon:textSize="12sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Now, the requirement is that, this layout file needs to be set in the custom view dynamically based on an user input. But, I receive the user input after the init() method of the custom view has already been called as this method gets called as soon as the FrameLayout given above gets loaded.

How do I dynamically set the layout file to the custom view based on user input? Can someone kindly help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to inflate R.layout.in_session_view_layout first and then when the user input arrive inflate another layout or you just have to inflate R.layout.in_session_view_layout after the user input arrived?

Comment: I have 2 kinds of layout :

R.layout.in_session_view_layout_1 and R.layout.in_session_view_layout. Either one needs to be inflated in the view after the user input arrived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I have understood your requirement correctly. If not please explain further.
You can do this.

In your custom view make a method called setLayout(int layoutId)

```
public void setLayout(int layoutId)
{
     removeAllViews();
     LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
     inflater.inflate(getContext(), layoutId, this);
}
```

When you have your user input you call

```
yourCustomView.setLayout(R.layout.new_layout);
```

*Disclaimer: All this is from memory and not tested so might not compile.*

Comment: So, in the init() method I will set any one of the layout file. Then override the previous layout based on user input; by using the setLayout method right ?

Comment: yes, the removeAllViews remove all the child views of your custom relative layout so you have a clean viewgroup on which you can add a new layout. Note though that this should work as expected if you are just using some static layout which don't require complex logic. For more complex scenario you might want to use a ViewPager or a ViewFlipper or other depending on your requirement.